# Enable only one submit button in an iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you enable only one form submit button when an file upload image is detected?

I am iterating over a model which returns a card. Each card has a form submit button which submits an image to the server. The form submits ok for each cards. My issue is, a card's submit button is disabled by default and once the user selects a image to upload, the button is no longer disabled. I am using React for this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return{
    enableButton: "disabled button",
    isFile: false
  }
},

fileInput(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({isFile: true});
  this.setState({enableButton: "button"});
},

renderedCards(){
 var cards = this.props.data.map( (q, i) => {
 var enableButton = this.state.enableButton;
 var url = "SOME_URL";

 <form action={url}
  id="new_quote_milestone"
  className="new_quote_milestone"
  encType="multipart/form-data"
  method="post">

    <input type="file" name="some_name]" id="some_id" onChange={this.fileInput}/>

  <span><input className={enableButton} value="Upload image" type="submit" /></span>
</form>

 });
 return(
   <div>{cards}</div>
 )
},

render(){
  return(
     <div>{this.renderedCards() ? this.renderedCards() : <Loader />}</div>
   )
 }
```

Now I have all buttons disabled and when I select an image to upload, all submit buttons are enabled. I dont want that. How I get only the card, with the image selected, submit button to enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is split with component into two. Then each form will be have own state:

```
var Cards = React.createClass({
    renderedCards() {
        var cards = this.props.data.map( (q, i) => {
            return <Card />
        });

        return (
            <div>{cards}</div>
        )
    },

    render() {
        return (
             <div>{this.renderedCards()}</div>
        )
     }
});

var Card = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            enableButton: "disabled button",
            isFile: false
        }
    },

    fileInput(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({isFile: true});
        this.setState({enableButton: "button"});
    },

    render() {
        var enableButton = this.state.enableButton;
        var url = "SOME_URL";

        return <form action={url}
            id="new_quote_milestone"
            className="new_quote_milestone"
            encType="multipart/form-data"
            method="post"
        >
            <input type="file" name="some_name]" id="some_id" onChange={this.fileInput}/>
            <span><input className={enableButton} value="Upload image" type="submit" /></span>
        </form>
    },
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/soaxv801/)

Or you can store in state indexes of form which have file.

Comment: I dont think I can use this method.

Comment: @Sylar Why not? It is a best and react way.

Comment: The hard part I face is the `form url`. This url has the id: `q.id`. How do I pass those values in?

Comment: You can pass it through props. [Example with props](https://jsfiddle.net/soaxv801/1/)

Comment: No. I have to map over each again.

Comment: I did not understand what the problem is. Can you provide more code?